# Content Page with Bindable Property not setting the value on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a tabbed page GroupDetailView that I create an instance of the MatchListView with the Bindable Property IdGroup receives the Binding Property of GroupDetailViewModel IdGroup, but the Bindable Property is not setting the value. What's wrong? Thanks.

.CS

```
public partial class GroupDetailView : TabbedPage
{
    public GroupDetailView (int id)
    {
        this.BindingContext = new GroupDetailViewModel (id);

        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

VIEWMODEL

```
private int idGroup;
public int IdGroup {
    get { return idGroup; }
    set {
        idGroup = value;
        this.Notify ("IdGroup");
    }
}

public GroupDetailViewModel (int id)
{
    this.IdGroup = id;
    this.GetGroup (id);
}
```

XAML

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ContentPage.Content>
            ...
        </ContentPage.Content>

    <local:MatchListView IdGroup="{ Binding IdGroup }" />
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

MATCHLISTVIEW

```
public partial class MatchListView : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IdGroupProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create<MatchListView, int> (c => c.IdGroup, default(int), BindingMode.OneWay, null);

    public int IdGroup
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IdGroupProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IdGroupProperty, value); }
    }

    public MatchListView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.BindingContext = new MatchListViewModel ();
    }...
```